# How to map a TIMESTAMP column to a ZonedDateTime JPA entity property?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mariadb, zoneddatetime

I'm using Spring data **jpa** and **mariadb** latest version, and **MariaDB 10.3.16**

```
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -> 2.1.5.RELEASE
...
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:2.1.5.RELEASE
...
|    +--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.3.10.Final
```

This is my Entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Note {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String gsn;

    @Column
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private NoteType type;

    @Column
    private String text;

    @Column
    private ZonedDateTime scheduleDt;

    @Column
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Instant createDt;

    @Column
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private ZonedDateTime updateDt;
}
```

When I persist my entity, Hibernate tries to save `ZonedDateTime` member as **DATETIME** column. But I want to use **TIMESTAMP** column instead of **DATETIME** column.

This is create DDL, what I see from log.

```
create table `note` (`id` integer not null, `create_dt` datetime,
    `gsn` varchar(255), `schedule_dt` datetime, `text` varchar(255),
    `type` varchar(255), `update_dt` datetime, primary key (`id`)) 
  engine=MyISAM
```

Here `create_dt`, `schedule_dt`, `update_dt` is created as `datetime` column type, what is not I wanted. (I don't like MyISAM, too).

How can I fix it?

---

Added because comment cannot express ddl.

When I use columnDefinition attribute, generated ddl is ...

```
create table `note` (`id` integer not null, `create_dt` datetime,
    `gsn` varchar(255), `schedule_dt` datetime, `text` varchar(255),
    `type` varchar(255), `update_dt` `TIMESTAMP`, primary key (`id`))
```

engine=MyISAM

There is unrequired '`' around TIMESTAMP.

Comment: Not really relaed, but why use a ZonedDateTime rather than an Instant or a LocalDateTime? The timestamp won't store the timezone stored in your ZonedDateTime anywhere, and you thus won't be able to get back a ZonedDateTime with the original time zone.

Comment: @JB Yes, you're right. Timezone is not recoverable. Anyway Instant, LocalDateTime do not work, too. Generated DDL uses DATETIME colume type.

Comment: @galex: your inline code formatting changes are fine, but software names and versions are not made more readable by putting them in bold. In general this is not necessary.

Comment: ok thanks for the advice, im new to stackoverflow

Comment: Not related to the question, but never use lombok's Data or EqualsAndHashcode for an Entity. You can check the decompiled files: lombok does not understand entities. Entities are not value objects. Lombok's implementation of equals and hascode is both incorrect and a potential performance killer. Check e.g. @vlad-mihalcea blog https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-implement-equals-hashcode-and-tostring-with-jpa-and-hibernate/ for a proper implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the column type using the @Column annotation:

```
@Column(columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP")  
@UpdateTimestamp
private ZonedDateTime updateDt;
```

Comment: This generates error. DDL is...   

    create table `note` (`id` integer not null auto_increment, `create_dt` datetime(6), `gsn` varchar(255), `schedule_dt` `TIMESTAMP`, `text` varchar(255), `type` varchar(255), `update_dt` datetime(6), primary key (`id`)) engine=InnoDB

Comment: Most likely the engine is different: your engine is InnoDB, however, in question defiinition MyISAM is used.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I added ddl above, because comment removes '`'

Answer (score 18):

JPA 2.2 offers support for mapping Java 8 Date/Time API, but only for the following types:

- [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://vladmihalcea.com/date-timestamp-jpa-hibernate/)
- [`java.time.LocalTime`](https://vladmihalcea.com/date-timestamp-jpa-hibernate/)
- [`java.time.LocalDateTime`](https://vladmihalcea.com/whats-new-in-jpa-2-2-java-8-date-and-time-types/)
- `java.time.OffsetTime`
- `java.time.OffsetDateTime`

However, Hibernate supports also [`ZonedDateTime`](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=338), like this.

When saving the `ZonedDateTime`, the following `Timestamp` is going to be sent to the `PreparedStatement`:

```
Timestamp.from( zonedDateTime.toInstant() )
```

And, when reading it from the database, the `ResultSet` will contain a `Timestamp` that will be transformed to a `ZonedDateTime`, like this:

```
ts.toInstant().atZone( ZoneId.systemDefault() )
```

Note that the `ZoneId` is not stored in the database, so basically, you are probably better off using a `LocalDateTime` if this `Timestamp` conversion is not suitable for you.

So, let's assume we have the following entity:

```
@Entity(name = "UserAccount")
@Table(name = "user_account")
public class UserAccount {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name", length = 50)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name", length = 50)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "subscribed_on")
    private ZonedDateTime subscribedOn;

    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

Notice that the `subscribedOn` attribute is a `ZonedDateTime` Java object.

When persisting the `UserAccount`:

```
UserAccount user = new UserAccount()
    .setId(1L)
    .setFirstName("Vlad")
    .setLastName("Mihalcea")
    .setSubscribedOn(
        LocalDateTime.of(
            2020, 5, 1,
            12, 30, 0
        ).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
    );

entityManager.persist(user);
```

Hibernate generates the proper SQL INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO user_account (
    first_name, 
    last_name, 
    subscribed_on, 
    id
) 
VALUES (
    'Vlad', 
    'Mihalcea', 
    '2020-05-01 12:30:00.0', 
    1
)
```

When fetching the `UserAccount` entity, we can see that the `ZonedDateTime` is properly fetched from the database:

```
UserAccount userAccount = entityManager.find(
    UserAccount.class, 1L
);

assertEquals(
    LocalDateTime.of(
        2020, 5, 1,
        12, 30, 0
    ).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()),
    userAccount.getSubscribedOn()
);
```

Comment: JDBC does not define support for `ZonedDateTime`, that is a non-standard extension, nor does JPA 2.2 define support for it (check your own blogpost and the JPA 2.2 changelog you link from that blogpost).

Comment: I updated the answer. Basically, Hibernate supports `ZonedDateTime`, and I explained how it does that even if JDBC does not offer native support for this type.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation of how it works under the hood. Is this covered somewhere in Hibernate docs? There are also a number of questions relating to timestamps in Hibernate. How is `Instant` JPA field processed? How `OffsetDateTime` is mapped to a `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` column etc.