# Why is the time changed when inserting in Mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I have a code in Spring with java 8 to insert the current date and time in my Mysql 5.7 database, the problem is that when I check the database it adds one more hour to the one that corresponds, the data type in the database is Datetime.

I already checked the time_zone in Mysql with SELECT @@ time_zone and it shows me: + ------------- + | @@ time_zone | + ------------- + | SYSTEM | + ------------- +

and also select now (); and it shows me the current time correctly.

My code is the following:

The class where I implement it:

```
LocalDateTime actual = LocalDateTime.now();
DTO.getPer().setDateUpdate(actual);
```

In the model:

```
@Column(name = "date_update")
private LocalDateTime dateUpdate;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried with `import java.sql.Timestamp;` like this `private Timestamp dateUpdate;`

Comment: MySQL keep all the dates in GMT time zone, this could be the problem I think.

Comment: @SagarGangwal It is the same.

Comment: @LunguDaniel The mysql time is displaying correctly, but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

This is definetly connected with TimeZones. You have UTC+1 time zone. `LocalDateTime` does not contain this informatin. Do use `ZonedDateTime` instead.

```
@Column(name = "date_update", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP")
private ZonedDateTime dateUpdate;
```

[How to map a TIMESTAMP column to a ZonedDateTime JPA entity property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56647962/how-to-map-a-timestamp-column-to-a-zoneddatetime-jpa-entity-property)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it still doesn't work, I have tested the application on another computer and it works fine, I have checked Mysql and Java time and it shows the correct time, I am currently working on Mac OSX Catalina.

Comment: @Jhon I think you use `ZonedDateTime` incorrectly. Could you provide a test case? Probably with in-memory DB?