# ZonedDateTime in json column of database table, when fetched, it changed to UTC

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, mariadb

I am developing a spring-boot project with MariaDB database.

I have a `Student` entity, which has a `Exam` property. In database, I would like to store the `Exam` property as a `json` field/column in `student` table.

The SQL for creating `student` table is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student (
    id bigint not null,
    exam json,
    first_name varchar(255),
    last_name varchar(255),
    primary key (id)
    ) engine=InnoDB;
```

The `Student` entity class is:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@TypeDefs({
    @TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class)
})
public class Student implements Serializable {
   ...

  @Column(columnDefinition = "LONGTEXT")
  @Type(type = "json")
  private Exam exam;
}
```

Those annotations you see above are meant to store the `exam` property as a JSON field in `student` table.

The `Exam` class is not annotated as a JPA entity, but a normal class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Exam implements Serializable {
    private ZonedDateTime startTime;
    private String code;
}
```

As you see, the `Exam` has a `ZonedDateTime` property. My question later is about it.

I have also `JpaRepository` class:

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, id> {
}
```

In my unit test code, I have a function to create a `Student` object:

```
public Student createStudentEntity() {
  // create exam, assign ZonedDateTime.now() to its "startTime" property 
  Exam exam = new Exam(ZonedDateTime.now(), "math01");

  Student student = new Student();
  student.setExam(exam);
  ...
  return student;
}
```

Then, I call this function in my test to save the student to database:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest
class StudentTest {

    @Autowired
    StudentRepository studentRepo;
    
    @Test
    void test_save_student()  {
        Student student = MyTestHelper.createStudentEntity();
        studentRepo.saveStudent(student);

        // The assertion fails due to the "startTime" of "exam" json object mismatch
        Assertions.assertEquals(student, studentRepo.getStudentById(student.getId()));
    }
```

The above test fails with message:

```
AssertionFailedError: expected: <Student(id=123,exam=Exam(startTime=2023-04-24T20:58:57.624489+03:00[Europe/Paris],...> but was: <Student(id=123,exam=Exam(startTime=2023-04-24T20:58:57.624489+03:00[UTC],...>
```

So, the error in short tells the mismatch in timezone:

- `exam` json value in created student is `exam=Exam(startTime=2023-04-24T20:58:57.624489+03:00[Europe/Paris]`,
- but when fetched from database, the fetched student contains `exam` json with value `exam=Exam(startTime=2023-04-24T20:58:57.624489+03:00[UTC]`.

Why the fetched student from database has `exam` field contains `startTime` that is in `[UTC]` while before persisting it to database the same field in `exam` json is treated as `[Europe/Paris]`?

**==== UPDATE ===**

I tried @Mar-Z's answer, updated my `Exam` class (which is not a JPA entity) to:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Exam implements Serializable {
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", timezone = "Europe/Paris")
    private ZonedDateTime startTime;
    private String code;
}
```

But it doesn't help, I still have the same issue: The fetched `student` from database having json field `exam` which contains the `startTime` part having `[UTC]` timezone.

Comment: Are you trying to persist the timezone as well as the date? What is the type of the column in the database? I don't believe JPA supports persisting the timezone as it isn't standard in databases - you are going to be stuck storing, converting and combining a timestamp/long data value with a timezone preference separately - see https://stackoverflow.com/q/56647962/496099

Comment: @Chris, the type of the column for `exam` field is `json` as indicated in my post. The `startTime` is a property of `Exam` class. So, I am persisting `Exam` property of `Student` as a `json`.

Comment: This is not a JPA issue but a Hibernate JSON serialization issue - show the JSON formed and stored in your DB with the options you've used to generate it and it might help show what is going wrong (serialization, deserialization or both). Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39086534/496099 as you might need to configure Jackson to support ZonedDateTime (and it is version specific)

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I'm facing it too.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the type ZonedDateTime in your Java code. It contains both time and the time zone.

With the call of ZonedDateTime.now() you will get default time zone of your application. Which is apparently Europe/Paris.

As you don't define any formatter for JSON serialization it will be serialized to number of milliseconds since January 1st, 1970. And it will be stored in the database as a number. In that moment the information about the time zone is lost. After reading back from the database this number will be deserialized to ZoneDateTime but using UTC.

That's why both times compares as not equal.

**Solution**

Use @JsonFormat annotation to provide time zone id in the string representation. (Please mind double V, not a W)

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ VV")
private ZonedDateTime startTime;
```

In the application.properties override Jackson defaults for adjusting the time zone to UTC.

```
spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-with-zone-id=true
spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-with-context-time-zone=false
spring.jackson.deserialization.adjust-dates-to-context-time-zone=false
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! Should I apply the @JsonFormat to the `Exam` field of `Student` or to the `startTime` field of `Exam` class?

Comment: and how to dynamically get the current timezon in this annotation instead of hardcode `Europe/pairs`?

Comment: I tried your solution, the same issue still exists. I hope you are aware that the whole `Exam` property of `Student` class is a `json` field, the issue is in the `startTime` of `Exam` and the `Exam` is not a JPA entity.  Please see my updated PO. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, my first solution was not perfect. Please check the edited version

Comment: With your edited version, I get error `No enum constant com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature.adjust-dates-to-context-time-zone`

Comment: Looks like a typo. Please check again. Should be: spring.jackson.deserialization.adjust-dates-to-context-time-zone